# How to make my view rotatable with the device orientation?

Tags: iphone

i am working on the Remote Desktop protocol in this i facing a lot of Problem. 
You guys are really good and help me in many critical situation .

My problem Goes like this:-

If i click on any button to connect to RDP after that if i wants to rotate the Device it is not happing

i made shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation Yes ,still the same

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Your connection request is blocking your UI.So better if you send your connection in in different thread not in main thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the info.plist file under the array "Supported interface orientations", you could add this:

```
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    <string> UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
</array>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: is this the answer you r looking for ? and if no y u accept this as answer? Now no one will give you other answer as thinking that the problem is solved